# Initialization of immutable value '' was never used

Tags: ios, swift, string, replace, custom-keyboard

I need to use replacingOccurrences to get a new string, but my question is, I can't use let in if.

I don't know how to do...confused so much till now

my issue just like what I quote in title, it is system warning.and my code as below:

```
let newlastfive1 = lastfive
        let newlastfive2 = lastfive
        let newlastfive3 = lastfive
        //replace aeoiu
     if (lastfive.range(of: "a", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            let newlastfive1 = lastfive.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "á")
            let newlastfive2 = lastfive.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "ǎ")
            let newlastfive3 = lastfive.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "à")
        }
        if (lastfive.range(of: "e", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
          newlastfive1.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "é")
            newlastfive2.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "ě")
            newlastfive3.replacingOccurrences(of: "e", with: "è")
        }
        if (lastfive.range(of: "o", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            newlastfive1.replacingOccurrences(of: "o", with: "ó")
            newlastfive2.replacingOccurrences(of: "o", with: "ǒ")
            newlastfive3.replacingOccurrences(of: "o", with: "ò")
        }
   
        if (lastfive.range(of: "i", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            newlastfive1.replacingOccurrences(of: "i", with: "í")
            newlastfive2.replacingOccurrences(of: "i", with: "ǐ")
            newlastfive3.replacingOccurrences(of: "i", with: "ì")
```

for I need to replace only one character in "aeiou",
this mean when we have two, we need to decide which one we need to pick.
for example, this string "hallo", in this case, we need to pick "a",not "a"&"o", only one character once.

priority should follow this : a>e>o>I>u>ü

Comment: Why not simply `let newlastfive1 = lastfive.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "á")` and so on directly without any `if`?

Comment: I need it, I have more condition for this, like  if {} if {} if {} if {}

Comment: maybe I should take a break to clear my brain now...

Comment: @Dennislay -- *"I have more condition..."* -- you should post your full question, not "here's is sort of what I need to do."

Comment: @DonMag thanks for reminding DonMag, you suggestion is helpful. i already try your code, very good, but still I prefer my way, so I am still studying my own code.

Comment: @Dennislay - it is still not at all clear what your goal is. Edit your question again, and try describing in **plain language** what you want. Include a few examples of strings showing the originals, and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you want 3 copies of the original string, each with letter-to-letter replacements?

Take a look at this code:

```
    let origString: String = "This is your test of looping replacement"

    // characters to replace
    let origChars: [String] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    
    // replace with these characters
    let replChars: [[String]] = [
        ["á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú"],
        ["ǎ", "ě", "ǐ", "ǒ", "ǔ"],
        ["à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù"],
    ]
    
    // mutable array of copies of the original string
    var resultStrings: [String] = Array(repeating: origString, count: replChars.count)
    
    // for each copy
    for i in 0..<resultStrings.count {
        // for each orig char
        for (oChar, rChar) in zip(origChars, replChars[i]) {
            // replace with replacement car
            resultStrings[i] = resultStrings[i].replacingOccurrences(of: oChar, with: rChar)
        }
    }
    
    // print the original string
    print(origString)
    
    // print the resulting replacement strings
    resultStrings.forEach {
        print($0)
    }
```

The output in the debug console is:

```
This is your test of looping replacement
Thís ís yóúr tést óf lóópíng réplácémént
Thǐs ǐs yǒǔr těst ǒf lǒǒpǐng rěplǎcěměnt
Thìs ìs yòùr tèst òf lòòpìng rèplàcèmènt
```

If you have more "replacement sets" you can add them to the `replChars` array:

```
    // replace with these characters
    let replChars: [[String]] = [
        ["á", "é", "í", "ó", "ú"],
        ["ǎ", "ě", "ǐ", "ǒ", "ǔ"],
        ["à", "è", "ì", "ò", "ù"],
        
        // add more sets
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
        ["ⓐ", "ⓔ", "ⓘ", "ⓞ", "ⓤ"],
    ]
```

Now the output in the debug console is:

```
This is your test of looping replacement
Thís ís yóúr tést óf lóópíng réplácémént
Thǐs ǐs yǒǔr těst ǒf lǒǒpǐng rěplǎcěměnt
Thìs ìs yòùr tèst òf lòòpìng rèplàcèmènt
Th3s 3s y45r t2st 4f l44p3ng r2pl1c2m2nt
Thⓘs ⓘs yⓞⓤr tⓔst ⓞf lⓞⓞpⓘng rⓔplⓐcⓔmⓔnt
```

Comment: this question is close now, will upload my answer later...

Comment: my answer is simply to remove let 
```if (Last3Letter.range(of: "u", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
        {
            Tone2Button.titleLabel?.text = Last3Letter.replacingOccurrences(of: "u", with: "ú")

Comment: sorry I am banned from, so this is the maximum length code I can give. I just dont use let in the case